# Wi-Fi "bootlooped" on Android

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

The Wi-Fi on my Android phone is "bootlooped". That means, that it permanently tries to start but never completes to do so. This is also visible in the Wi-Fi menu, where it says "Turning Wi-Fi on...". As suggested for similar problems I tried deleting the files

```
/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
/data/misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf
```

but it didn't help. What can I do to resolve this problem?
I got it as a used phone so I don't know, if the Wi-Fi module is working. Switching the daughterboard did, however, not change anything.

My system:
Fairphone FP1
Android 4.4.2

---

The command `cat /proc/kmsg | grep wifi` doesn't give any results. When I execute `logcat | grep wifi` only the following line is printed several times: `D/WifiController( 768): wifiSleepPolicy:2`.

Comment: Any error messages available on `logcat` or `/proc/kmsg`?

Comment: The command `cat /proc/kmsg | grep wifi` doesn't give any results. When I execute `logcat | grep wifi` only the following line is printed several times: `D/WifiController(  768): wifiSleepPolicy:2`.

Comment: Don't use `grep` use your brain, otherwise you may miss important messages (e.g. messages that just use the wifi chip code-name. And don't write the results in the comments edit and extend your question instead.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really know what to look out for.